# Realm fileExists is always true

Tags: swift3, realm

I want to copy preloaded realm file, so I do:

Copied my file to project navigator named `default.realm`. Then check if `fileExists:`:

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")
let destPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
    //File exist, do nothing
    print("File exist")
} else {
    do {
        //Copy file from bundle to Realm default path
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: destPath!)
        print("Copied")
    } catch {
        print("\n",error)
    }
}
```

And it always returns true, so I can't copy my realm file.

Comment: Do you have a code `let realm = try! Realm()` as an instance variable in a view controller? View controllers are instantiated from Storyboard BEFORE `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Please make sure that and modify them to `lazy var realm = try! Realm()`, then delete the app from the simulator, then re-try it.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi thank you very much. All problem was in `let`!

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code in Simulator after resetting the contents and settings (`Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...`) and it appeared to execute as intended.

If you've previously used Realm in your project (i.e. testing), it's probably seeing the old `default.realm` file.

Comment: I reset the contents and settings, and it still returns `file exists`. How and where realm creates a new `default.realm` file? It seems I check if file exists after realm creates default file. I check in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Comment: Then second issue is when I hardly copied my realm file, `let realm = try! Realm()` returns empty results...