# Realm iOS issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I want to load prefilled Realm DB in my app. So what I do:

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")
let destPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
let fileManager = FileManager.default

if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destPath!) {
    //File exist, do nothing
    print("File exists")
} else {
    do {
        //Copy file from bundle to Realm default path
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundlePath!, toPath: destPath!)
        print("Copied")
    } catch {
        print("\n",error)
    }
}
```

This part always returns true, I get `file exists` even I reset simulator content and settings.
Second: when I hardly copy my realm db file without checking if file exists, this code

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var posts: Results<Post> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(Post.self)
    }
}
```

returns empty posts on first run. When I run app second time I get prefilled db. What do I wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access realm before running your piece of code? If yes then it probably creates automatically an empty .realm file, but then your `fileExistsAtPath` method would return true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm fileExists is always true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545490/realm-fileexists-is-always-true)

Comment: Do you have a code `let realm = try! Realm()` as an instance variable in a view controller? View controllers are instantiated from Storyboard BEFORE `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Please make sure that and modify them to `lazy var realm = try! Realm()`, then delete the app from the simulator, then re-try it.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi thank you very much. All problem was in `let`!